# Number of Rows in UITableView Needs to Differ after Delete

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a table with multiple sections.  When a given section has no rows I return 1 from `numerOfRowInSection` and then create some default text.  I don't allow this row to be selected or edited.

The problem is that this section does allow the deleting of rows when there is data (again I disable this when there is not data and I am showing my default text).  However, let's say there is one row of actual data in this section.  When the user deletes this row it should then reload the table and show my default text as no data exists for this section anymore.  What actually happens is an app terminating error because after the delete it is expecting 0 rows (1 row prior, 1 row delete, 0 rows result).  In my code though when rows is 0 I return 1 as mentioned so the math doesn't work and the error shuts everything down.

Question: How can I keep a default row when the table is empty but allow deletes such that when the last row of data is deleted it will allow my 1 of default text rather than no rows as it expects?

Code for delete:

```
         - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
            {
                [self deleteFav:indexPath.row];
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
    }
```

Code to handle number of rows and default:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) return [self.channelIDArray count];
    else if (section == 1)
        if ([self.favChannelIDArray count]>0) return [self.favChannelIDArray count];
        else return 1;
}
```

Error:

2014-07-31 19:47:19.194 ephIM[3183:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: Show your code for handling the deletions.

Comment: Also, please show your error log.

Comment: I added both to my OP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't taking into account your extra row when there are no normal rows. You need to add that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self deleteFav:indexPath.row];
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        if (indexPath.section == 1 && self.favChannelIDArray.count == 0) {
            // This tells the table to insert the "dummy" row you want
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:indexPath.section] ] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This got me in the right direction as I didn't realize you couldn't simply reload the table data and this stage.  As a note, "initForRow" does not appear to be valid.  Here is what I used: [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

Comment: I fixed the typo for the index path. You can simply reload the table at this stage but calling `reloadData` is a bit overkill when you just need to add/delete one row.

Comment: I agree, I am not calling reload data.  My thought was this would be the approach after the record was deleted.  However, that doesn't work as noted.  Your answer is of course the right way to go.  Thanks again.